# How do i use exception handling with custom errorType?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

This question is about exception handling. Basically, i need to create an exception class but instead of what i have been taught where it is just

```
class ExpenditureException(Exception):
    pass
```

My current exception class needs to be something like that

```
class ExpenditureException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, errorType):
        super().__init__(message)
        self._errorType = errorType

    @property
    def errorType(self):
        return self._errorType

class Expenditure:
    def __init__(self, expenditureDate, amount, expenditureType):
        self._date = expenditureDate
        self._amount = amount
        if amount < 0:
            raise ExpenditureException(f'{amount} cannot be negative')
        self._type = expenditureType
```

The problem I am having is that how do i use the errorType? In the above error i have raised, i need to place it under the errorType 'Amount' but i have no idea how to do so. Do i use a dictionary?

Comment: You need to pass the the `errorType` argument when you raise the exception, i.e.: `raise ExpenditureException(f'{amount} cannot be negative', expenditureType)`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than maintain an `errorType` attribute, in the exception class, why not use inheritance for what it was meant? In other words, I suggest that you create an inheritance hierarchy of exception classes.  For example:

```
class ExpenditureException(Exception):
    pass

class AmountException(ExpenditureException):
    def __init__(self, amount):
        super().__init__(f'The amount, {amount}, cannot be negative')

class DateException(ExpenditureException):
    def __init__(self, date):
        super().__init__(f'The date, {date}, is invalid')


class Expenditure:
    def __init__(self, expenditureDate, amount, expenditureType):
        self._date = expenditureDate
        self._amount = amount
        if amount < 0:
            raise AmountException(amount)
        if date[0:4] != '2019':
            raise DateException(date)
        self._type = expenditureType

try:
    e = Expenditure('2019-11-01', -1, 'Travel')
except ExpenditureException as ex:
    print(ex.__class__.__name__, ': ', ex, sep='')
```

Prints:

```
AmountException: The amount, -1, cannot be negative
```

You can always test the actual class type to see what type of exception you got, for instance:

```
if isinstance(ex, AmountException): do_something()
```

This substitutes for maintaining an explicit `errorType` attribute.